# How to undo all changes to an edited image in RawTherapee?

Tags: image-processing, rawtherapee, keyboard-shortcuts

## My Problem

I am editing an image in [RawTherapee](http://www.rawtherapee.com/), and I am not satisfied with the result. I want to undo all changes and start editing the original image. If possible, I would be happy to see a list of changes and selectively undo some of them.

## What have I tried

- Searched the [keyboard shortcuts](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Keyboard_Shortcuts)
- Searched [some forums](https://discuss.pixls.us/t/history-and-or-reset-seeing-our-footprints/1843)

## My question

**How to undo all changes to an edited image in RawTherapee?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch to the File Browser view and find your image. Right click on the little green check mark and select "Processing profile options" followed by "Clear". That will reset the sidecar file to the unedited / default state.

For partial reverts, in the History pane on the left, click on the step you're interested in keeping - the ones after (below) that will be undone. Selective reverts are a bit more involved, and involve the "Apply (partial)" option under the above-mentioned "Processing profile options".

Answer (score 4):

RawTherapee, and other raw processors, usually create sidecar files containing the edits you've made. If you delete the sidecar file while RawTherapee is closed, the next time you open the image, RawTherapee will start with the default profile. If I recall correctly, the sidecar file is named the same as the image with the extension `pp3`. If you have multiple images you want to reset, it would be faster to delete sidecars than to clear edits for each image from within RawTherapee.